# Preprocessing find max between #define

Tags: macros, max, c-preprocessor, x-macros

I have two header files making the same define with different values:

```
 file1.h:
          #define NUM_OF_TREES 10
 file2.h:
          #define NUM_OF_TREES 20
```

In another file i want to define 
     limits.h
              #define MAX_NUM_OF_TREES 
how can I assign the maximum in static time (preprocessing) using macros?

Answer (score 0):

file1.h:

```
  #define NUM_OF_TREES 10
  typedef unsigned char NUM1[NUM_OF_TREES];
```

file2.h:

```
  #define NUM_OF_TREES 20
  typedef unsigned char NUM2[NUM_OF_TREES];
```

file3.c:

```
  typedef union {
      NUM1;
      NUM2;
  } FOR_MAX_SIZE;

 #define MAX_NUM_OF_TREES sizeof (FOR_MAX_SIZE);
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.